# java.lang.NullPointerException Google Calendar API Quickstart

Tags: java, google-calendar

Решил тестировать пример Google Calendar API Quickstart по этой ссылке https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java.
При запуске получаю:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at Quickstart.authorize(Quickstart.java:64)
at Quickstart.getCalendarService(Quickstart.java:86)
at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:98)
```

в строке:

```
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

не могу понять почему... 
Файл client_secret.json кладу в папку с проектом. Пробовал указывать абсолютный путь, но все тоже самое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Положите файл **client_secret.json** в папку **src/main/resources/**

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибка исчезла.